# How do you configure PyCharm to quick-fix imports from installed third-party code?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm trying to transition from PyDev to PyCharm, but the one killer feature of PyDev that I absolutely cannot live without is quick-fixing imports.

In PyDev, I can type out code that uses a class I haven't yet imported within that file, press Cmd-1, and it'll pop up a list of every instance of that class that PyDev knows about, in both my own code and in all the code installed in my virtualenv. Selecting one of those instances will add the appropriate import line at the top of the file.

PyCharm has a similar feature, where you press Alt-Enter to open the "Intention Actions", and a variety of things including "import this name" come up. But "import this name" only seems to appear if the unknown name matches code that's in my project folder. It doesn't appear if the name I want to import is in my installed third-party apps within site-packages.

I've already confirmed that site-packages is in my interpreter's path list, so I don't think that's the problem.

How do I make the "import this name" Intention Action consider third-party code as an importable source?

EDIT:
The specific code I'm having trouble with is the [Wagtail starter project](https://wagtail.io/developers/). To reproduce, create a fresh VirtualEnv, follow steps 1 and 2 with that VE active, then add the "mysite" folder as a pure Python project in PyCharm. Edit `search/views.py`, delete line 4 (the import that brings in `Page`), then go to line 13 (where `Page` is used) and press Alt-Enter to open the Intentions Actions popup.

I would expect "import this name" to appear, and offer to add back the import from line 4 that was deleted. But "import this name" does not appear. However, if you start a new line and type "HomePage" and open the Intentions popup again, you will see "import this name", and it will let you import the `HomePage` class from `home.models`, which is in the project folder.

Comment: Strange, for me (using PyCharm 5.0.3 in Ubuntu) AutoImport worked pretty much out of the box. Can you see all the packages listed in settings > Project > Project Interpreter?

Comment: Yes, I can see "wagtail" in the Project Interpreter package list. Speaking of which, I'll go update my question with a specific example that isn't working.